# Layout scrolling ripple effect

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

How could this scrolling behavior be accomplished?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlAq4.png)

To be specific, I need the wave effect to be shown whenever I try to scroll and reach the limit of a layout. Is there some property that I can tweak?

Answer (score 0):

To get this wave effect, use any horizontally or vertically `scrollable` view as a `container layout` in your layout XML.

For example: `ScrollView`, `HorizontalScrollView`, `NestedScrollView`

List and Grid layouts like `ListView`, `RecyclerView` also has this scrolling effect.